# ExtJS - Custom button call function from controller?

Tags: button, extjs

I have a button in the view:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Click me!',
    handler: 'onClick' // <- call function from controller
}]
```

Now I want to change that button to custom button (contains a text and a link), just like this:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'component',
    html: getLink()
}]
```

In same js file, I have a function:

```
function getLink() {
    // Doing something
    return '<div>Hi, <a href="...">Click me!</a></div>';
}
```

I want to call 'onClick' function when I click custom button. How can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add click event handler in your controller with `afterrender`:

View:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'component',
    html: getLink(),
    itemId: 'myLink'
}]
```

Controller:

```
var controller = this;

controller.control({
    // Selector for your link parent component
   'yourSelector': {
      afterrender: function(component) {
           component.down('#myLink').on('click', function() {
                controller.onClick();
           });
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element` and `delegate` on your `listener`, for example:

```
{
            xtype: 'box',
            html: '<div>Hi, <a class="custom-btn">Click me!</a></div>',
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    element: 'el',
                    delegate: '.custom-btn',
                    fn: function() {
                        console.log('click!');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11mt

Answer (score 0):

```
xtype: 'component',
autoEl:{
    tag: 'a',
    href: '',
    onClick: 'nameYouFunction'
}
```